# Technique used to analyze solution of rotational invariant problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering, boundary-conditions

I am reading chapter 12.6 of Shankar's QM, and got completely confused when he tries to explain why we impose the limit $rV(r)\to 0$. Why in this step do we put $$U=f(r)e^{\pm ikr}$$ and expect $f(r)$ tends to a constant?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We put in
$$
U=f(r) e^{\pm i k r}
$$
because this is the most general form of a spherical wave. $f(r)$ is the amplitude envelope and $e^{\pm ikr}$ is the oscillatory part.

The reason we take $f(r)$ to be constant is that we want it to represent a *free particle* far from the origin. Simply put, we don't want an electron on the other side of the city to be affected by the potential we apply in our lab. A free particle must have a constant $f(r)$ since the Schroedinger equation implies that $f(r) \neq const$ only if there is a potential term, which means that the particle is not free.

Comment: Thank you:)) It helps a lot.